# cordova ios 6.1.0 wkwebview some xhr POST fails

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors, wkwebview, cordova-ios

as everyone dev. using ionic stack, also we are moving into the new wkwebview due to the Apple requirements.

We already provide a build to ios without any kind of warning ( about uiwebview old code ) but we're still encountering a problem performing SOME POST calls.

**Settings**

We have already set cors server side ( Apache ) like below:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.hrd.auth.tomcat7.cors.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>app://myapp, http://localhost:9090</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,User-Agent,DEVICE_ID</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param> -->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here below instead, the current APP configuration:

```
<description>An app from company S.r.l.</description>
<author email="sviluppo@mycompany.com" href="https://www.mycompany.com/">       Contact us  </author>
<content src="index.html" />

<!-- Permissions -->

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

<!-- Preferences -->

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1500" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>

<!-- Hooks -->

<hook src="www/hooks/fwk-after-prepare-hooks.js" type="after_prepare" />
<hook src="www/hooks/fwk-after-plugin-add-hooks.js" type="after_plugin_add" />
<hook src="www/hooks/fwk-after-prepare-copy-build-extra-hooks.js" type="after_prepare" />
<hook src="www/hooks/fwk-after-compile-hooks.js" type="after_compile" />
<hook src="www/hooks/fwk-before-build-hooks.js" type="before_build" />

<!-- iOS -->

<platform name="ios">

    <!-- CORS -->
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="iosScheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="myapp" />

    <!-- Resouces -->
    <resource-file src="www/GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    <icon height="20" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-20.png" width="20" />
    ...
</platform>


<!-- PLUGINS LIST -->

<!-- LIST -->
<!-- Don't modify this plugins list because it's generate-->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="0.1.9"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-calendar" spec="4.6.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-call-number" spec="1.0.1"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.1.0">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow_the_app_to_use_your_camera" />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow_the_app_to_access_your_photos" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="1.2.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="6.2.0">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="2553981324652029" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="com.mycompany.myapp" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="6.0.2"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="4.0.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.2.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="3.0.3">
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow_the_app_to_access_your_photos" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.4"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple" spec="0.1.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie" spec="1.0.6"/>

<engine name="ios" spec="6.1.0" />
```

**Problem**

The APP performs a successful POST call for login, with the following xhr details

```
"{\"method\":\"POST\",
\"post\":\"{
    \\\"username\\\":\\\"username\\\",
    \\\"password\\\":\\\"password\\\"
}\",
\"url\":\"http://192.168.1.129:8080/go/rest/security/appLogin/MY_APP_LOGIN\",
\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\",
\"DEVICE_ID\":\"a91d602c140079f2e848f39e33a6ca88\",
\"Accept\":\"application/json,text/plain,*/*\"},
\"withCredentials\":true}"
```

BUT, in this call ( performed after having been authenticated ), is failing:

```
 "{\"method\":\"POST\",
\"post\":\"{
    \\\"test\\\":\\\"test\\\"
}\",
\"url\":\"http://192.168.1.129:8080/go/rest/security/userInfo\",
\"headers\":{
    \"Accept\":\"application/json,text/plain,*/*\",
    \"Content-Type\":\"application/json;charset=utf-8\"
},
\"withCredentials\":true}"
```

**Environment Configuration**

- ionic-bundle that contains following stack
  ** ionic.js 1.3.2
  ** angularJS 1.5.3
- cordova 9.0.0
- cordova-ios 6.1.0

Have someone any idea for why that kind of call fails?

**FAQ**

1. Unlike the first one ( login call ) the second one doesn't reach server CorsFilter.java class, so call "not exit from the APP"
2. Our widget environment, unlike the mobile one, has been fixed for POST calls just putting inside call payload mocked data, in order to complain w3c browser specifications.

Very many thanks in advance
Simone

Comment: do you face zoom issue in 6.1.0, when click on input if font size is less than 16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered issues about calls not reaching server CorsFilters.java class ( so impossibile to get some debug instance ).

Reading our sever log we discovered this row

```
192.168.x.x - - [02/Sep/2020:17:40:09 +0200] "OPTIONS /go/rest/security/userInfo HTTP/1.1" 401 7361 4286
```

This is a know well problems about preflight POST request so - we just add in our web.xml conf. file the following property

```
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>REST</web-resource-name>
    <description>REST services</description>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method-omission>OPTIONS</http-method-omission> <<--- add this row
</web-resource-collection>
```

In this way, all OPTIONS request were'll be accepted and NOT rejected!

Hope this will help someone with a weeks headache ;)

Simon

Comment: We have just the same problem with an App. Some preflights get cut off on the server. Our server is PHP 7 using the YII2 framework. Would anyone have a solution similar to the one discussed here for Java? It would save our lives. Our App use cordova 6.1.1. Please, We are quite worried and without solutions